# How to print the desired file from a directory?

Tags: c

In this code, I am printing all the files present in the base directory. But I want to be more specific and print only the desired file that I want. How can I do this?

```
int specificSelection(char *basePath, char *specificFile){
    struct dirent *dp;
    DIR *dir;
    int count=0;

    if ( NULL != ( dir = opendir ( basePath))) {
        while ( NULL != ( dp = readdir(dir))) {
            if (strcmp ( dp->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp ( dp->d_name, "..") != 0) {
                strcpy(specificFile, dp->d_name);
                if ( dp->d_type == DT_REG) {
                    printf("%s\n", specificFile);
                }
            }
        }
        closedir(dir);
    }
    else {
        perror (basePath);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(){
  char pathname1[200] = "/home/runner/TestC1";
  char path[100] = "filename.txt";

  listdir(pathname1, path);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you use the same condition you are using for "." and ".."?

Comment: Instead of checking whether it's not `.` or `..`, you could check whether it's the file you need - by the way your current code will crash or at least corrupt memory as soon as you come by any file with a name longer than the name that you passed in, you can't use `strcpy` that way (and in fact you shouldn't use `strcpy` *ever*, for this very reason that it can't limit the length)

Comment: At the moment, you're copying the filenames into the memory pointed by `specificFile`. It sounds like `specificFile` contains a filename already (and should probably be `const`). In that case, you need to compare the files with `specificFile` using `strcmp` until you find the one you want.

Comment: Please show how you call `specificSelection`. What's the purpose of `strcpy(specificFile, dp->d_name)`? Why not simply `printf("%s\n", dp->d_name)`? What is the `specificFile` parameter anyway? You have >50 points of reputation so I suppose you know what a [mcve] is

Comment: @user3121023 that would be a pretty convoluted way to check if a file exists in a directory and print its name if it exists...

Comment: @Jabberwocky I updated the code. You can check it.

Comment: " I am printing all the files" - all files or all file names?

Comment: @i486 All the filenames

Comment: @Skywifibrand what should the output be if `filename.txt` exists? What should the output be if `filename.txt` does not exist? [Edit] and show some examples, it's very unclear what you want.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I wrote `if(strcmp(specificFile, dp->d_name) == 0)` instead of `strcpy()` and it worked.

Comment: @user3121023 I used `strcmp()` and it worked.

Comment: @Skywifibrand That's really complicated. Your code with `strcmp` is basically just checking if the file exists. There are much simpler ways to do this for example with [`stat`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lstat.2.html). The code would merely take 3-4 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Your code basically just check if the file exists:

You can do this in a much simpler way by using the `access` function:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int specificSelection(char *basePath, char *specificFile){
  char filename[1000];
  strcpy(filename, basePath);
  strcat(filename, specificFile); // filename contains now the absolute path to
                                  // the file, e.g. "/home/runner/TestC1/filename.txt"

  if (access(filename, F_OK) == 0)  // check if file exists
  {
    printf("%s\n", filename);       // print filename if it exists
  }

  return 0;
}
...
```

Disclaimer:

- this is untested code, it may not work
- there is no error checking
- the code will not work if the total length of the file path exceeds 999.

You could use the [`stat`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lstat.2.html) function instead of the `access` function, which allows more control.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `fnmatch` along with `scandir` :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <dirent.h>
#include <fnmatch.h>

static char *filename;

static int selection(const struct dirent *entry)
{
    if (fnmatch(filename, entry->d_name, FNM_PATHNAME | FNM_PERIOD) == 0)   
        return 1;

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char pathname[200] = "/home/runner/TestC1";
    char path[100] = "filename.txt";

    filename = path;

    struct dirent **list;

    int nb_entries = scandir(pathname, &list, selection, NULL);

    if (nb_entries >= 0) {

        if (nb_entries == 1) { /* found */

            printf("%s\n", list[0]->d_name);
            free(list[0]);
        }    
        free(list);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this is just an example.
You can also easily extend this code to use regular expression if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

In this section:

```
if (strcmp ( dp->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp ( dp->d_name, "..") != 0) {
            strcpy(specificFile, dp->d_name);
            if ( dp->d_type == DT_REG) {
                printf("%s\n", specificFile);
            }
        }
```

the logic will output any found string that does not == a `.` or `..`, and for which its `d_type == DT_REG`.  This does not seem to match the stated need:

> *"But I want to be more specific and print only the desired file that I want"*.

Consider the following modification using [strstr()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strstr.htm)

```
if (strstr( dp->d_name, specificFile) ) {
   if( dp->d_type == DT_REG) {
         printf("%s\n", specificFile);//if only filename is desired, 
         printf("%s\n", dp->d_name);//or if entire line is desired, 
   }
}
```